# How do I pass this.params through map function ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have parent with two props: entities and options. I would like to send for each entity the options as params. How can I achieve that? I tried with:

```
class FormsList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    };  
    render(){
        var items = this.props.entities.map(function(entity){
            return(
                <Child data={entity} key={entity.Id} moredata={this.props.options}/>
            );
        });
        return(
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
                <List children={items}/>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );      
    };
};
```

I know that params are not accessible in entities.map function body, but how should I pass options to child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your map function in order for it to have access to the right `this`.

```
var items = this.props.entities.map(function(entity){
    return (
        <Child data={entity} key={entity.Id} moredata={this.props.options}/>
    );
}.bind(this);
```

Alternatively, you can use arrow function syntax:

```
var items = this.props.entities.map(entity => {
    return (
        <Child data={entity} key={entity.Id} moredata={this.props.options}/>
    );
};
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!

Comment: Instead of `.bind(this)`, pass `this` as second argument to `.map`.